# $injector:unpr Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando criar um service no ionic 1 mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: heartTeamSrvcProvider <- heartTeamSrvc <- teamCtrl

Código heartTEamSrvc

```
(function) {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('firstApp');

 app.factory('heartTeamSrvc', function($http, $scope) {

    var heartTeam = [];

    return {
        getHeartTeam: function() {
            return $http.get('json/heartTeams.json').then(function(response){
                heartTeam = response;
                return heartTeam;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

})

Controller

```
  $scope.listHeart = function(heartTeamSrvc) {
            $scope.heartTeam = getHeartTeam();
        }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

**EDITADO**

NOVO CTRL

```
 function listHeartTeam(response) {
            this.heartTeam = getHeartTeam();
        }
```

Comment: Você colocou a importação pro `script` da `factory`?

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo, esqueci de fazer a importação na index. Obrigado.

Comment: @Leonardo pera ai que eu vou te ajudar, rs

Comment: Agradeço @DiogoHenriqueFragosodeOliv olhei o tutorial que vc me mandou e notei que boa parte code que foi feito não é o recomendado na publicação rsrs

Comment: kkkk @Leonardo, rlx que quando eu comecei no Angular estava mais perdido que cego em tiroteio, kkkk

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Verifique a importação do `.js` no seu `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Ele está falando que não reconhece o provider pelo motivo que vc não injetou o provider(heartTeamSrvc) no controller, possivelmente sua factory vai quebrar também pelo motivo que você não injetou o $http nem o $scope neles
[Siga esse tutorial de boas praticas para montar seus Controllers, Factorys, Services e ETC](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/i18n/pt-BR.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection)

ajuste sua factory:

```
(function () {
'use strict';


angular.module('firstApp')
.factory('heartTeamSrvc', heartTeamSrvc)


heartTeamSrvc.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];

function heartTeamSrvc($http, $scope) {

    var heartTeam = [];

    return {
        getHeartTeam: function() {
            return $http.get('json/heartTeams.json').then(function(response){
                heartTeam = response;
                return heartTeam;
            });
        }
    }
  }

})
```

Não esqueça que seu controller vai precisar de ajuste também, tente fazer sozinho qualquer coisa se não conseguir, adiciona o Controller na sua pergunta que eu te ajudo.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta Diogo. Importei o JS na index, digitei seu code no meu service e infelizmente está dando o mesmo erro Estou importanto heartTeamSrvc no meu controller e estou lendo o tutorial que você me passou, estou um pouco perdido, mas acho que vou conseguir.

Comment: @Leonardo, tranquilo, qualquer coisa, atualiza na sua pergunta o Controller e o Service que você está editando. Tenta usar o debug do Chrome, coloca o brack-point bem no começo do código, e verifica se ele reconhece o heartTeamSrvc

Comment: Diogo me perdi um pouco no ctrl, vou editar a pergunta e inserir o código q modifiquei.

Comment: Acho que não é isso mas não custa perguntar né rsrs